# Image not rendering in IE8

Tags: javascript, css, html, internet-explorer-8

We have the following css working fine in IE11, Chrome and Firefox. But the image is not rendering properly in IE8.

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 46px;
width: 144px;
font-size: 0;
color: transparent;
background: transparent url("../test.png") no-repeat 0 1px;
background-size: 144px 46px;
color: #fff;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In what way is it not rendering properly? Is the image invisible?  Is it improperly aligned?

Comment: [`background-size`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#color_and_background)  is not supported in IE8.

Comment: Just stop supporting IE8, everone else has, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

the `background-size` property is not supported in IE8. Support for this property starts with IE9.

Comment: Thanks @racecarjonathan, is there any alternative for setting the background size in IE8. I explored a few options like Filters but couldn't get it working.

Comment: just this,  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532969(v=vs.85).aspx but, other than that, there's no other way that i'm aware of, unfortunately...any reason you need to support IE8?